# Show all programs from all monitors in the taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

The Windows 7 taskbar only shows the programs running on the current monitor. Applications running on the second monitor are listed in the taskbar of the second monitor. Is it possible to make the taskbar show all programs from all Monitors and not only from the ones running on the current monitor?

Comment: I've never experienced this. What program is it? Maybe a screenshot would help.

Comment: Sorry, my problem was partly due to a misconfiguration on my side. I edited the question accordingly to explain my real problem.

Comment: You have two different taskbars?

Comment: I apologize again, I'm only using Windows at work. Seems like my problem was caused by a configuration specific for my work PC. I've finally found a solution. Thanks for your time

Comment: Oh ok, no problem. Glad it was fixed.